# Обновление div'a после добавления комментария

Tags: jquery, обновление, html, ajax

Как обновить div после добавления комментария? К примеру, как в Facebook и VK. Знаю ,что нужен jQuery AJAX, но я в нём полный ЛАЛ

Comment: http://bit.ly/14o8NjH

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
//здесь обновлять див
$('.result').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, он обновляться будет только у меня? А у других пользователей как?

Comment: У всех, кто откроет страницу со скриптом.

Comment: плюсанул. Вы же всё ещё считаете этот ответ верным? ))